# Use different stemmers in the same index

Tags: elasticsearch, lexical-analysis

I'm building a dictionary and want to use elasticsearch as the search engine. It should support multiple languages, so my database looks similar to this:

```
| left_lang | right_lang | left_word | right_word |
| de        | en         | Schuh     | shoe       |
| da        | de         | sko       | Schuh      |
```

On which level can define different analyzer settings (like stemmers etc)? Can I set different  settings per field of a document? E.g. in the first document, use German settings for the left_word and English for right_words and in the second, use Danish for left_words and German for right_words? Or can I just define these on type or index level?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you can define those settings per-field.  You can even define fields that are analyzed with multiple language settings using the "[Multi-field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type.html)" mappings.

```
{
  "settings":{
     "index":{
        "analysis":{
           "analyzer":{
              "analyzer_english":{
                 "tokenizer":[...],
                 "filter":[...]
              },
              "analyzer_german":{
                 "tokenizer":[...],
                 "filter":[...]
              }
           }
        }
     }
  },
  "mappings":{
     "test":{
        "properties":{
           "left_word":{
              "analyzer":"analyzer_german",
              "type":"string"
           },
           "right_word":{
              "analyzer":"analyzer_english",
              "type":"string"
           },
           "combo_word":{
              "type":"multi_field",
              "fields":{
                 "combo_word":{
                    "analyzer":"analyzer_german",
                    "type":"string"
                 },
                 "combo_english":{
                    "analyzer":"analyzer_english",
                    "type":"string"
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```